# writing test conditions in a map_if function : apply function on all dataframes with a column that includes specific values

Tags: r, list, select, tidyverse, purrr

Once again i'm struggling with map functions of purrr.

I've got a list of dataframes,  all with ID and Name columns.

I want to perform some recoding and then aggregation on rows with some specific values.
For that purpose,  i've got another dataframe with a vector of ID and newID that I want to replace before doing some aggregration (sum all numeric variable).

I know how to perform this on one df (see II/), but I don't know what test to write in a map_if function to apply thoses operations on all dataframes where column ID includes some values of new newIDdf$ID (here dataframe B and C).

Any ideas ?

```r
## I/  2 objects 
 # a list of df
 list_df <- list(A = data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "Z", "Y"),
                                Name = c("a_name", "b_name", "c_name", "Z_name", "Y_name"), 
                                Var1 = rnorm(5),
                                Var2 = rnorm(5),
                                Var3 = rnorm(5)),
                B = data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "z1", "z2", "z3"),
                               Name = c("a_name", "b_name", "z1_name", "z2_name", "z3_name"),
                               Var1 = rnorm(5),
                               Var2 = rnorm(5)),
                C = data.frame(ID =  c("y1", "y2", "z1", "z2", "z3"),
                               Name = c("y1_name", "y2_name", "z1_name", "z2_name", "z3_name"),
                               Var1 = rnorm(5),
                               Var2 = rnorm(5)))
 
 # a dataframe of correspondance for aggregation operations
 newIDdf <- data.frame(ID =  c("y1", "y2", "z1", "z2", "z3"),
                       IDagr =  c("Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z"))
 
 ## II/ what I want to do (but on 1 df)
# example on 1 df
 
 On1df <- list_df[["B"]] %>% 
   mutate(ID = reduce2(newIDdf$ID, newIDdf$IDagr, 
                           .init= ID, 
                           str_replace)) %>%
   mutate(Name = case_when(ID == "Z" ~ "Z_name",
                         ID == "Y" ~ "Y_name",
                             TRUE ~ Name)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate_if(is.numeric, ~list(. = sum(.))) %>% 
   distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)

## III/ What I really want to achieve
 # what if I want to do that simultaneously on df B and C 
 # I mean applying thoses operations on dataframes 
# where column ID includes some values of new newIDdf$ID
 
 list_df_output <- list_df %>% map_if( .p = ~ any(ID %in% newIDdf$ID), ### what test to put here ? (because this doesn't work)
                                       ~ mutate(.x, ID = reduce2(newIDdf$ID, newIDdf$IDagr, 
                                                             .init= ID, 
                                                             str_replace)) %>%
                                         mutate(.,Name = case_when(ID == "Z" ~ "Z_name",
                                                                 ID == "Y" ~ "Y_name",
                                                                 TRUE ~ Name)) %>%
                                         group_by(., ID) %>% 
                                         mutate_if(., is.numeric, ~list(. = sum(.))) %>% 
                                         distinct(., ID, .keep_all = TRUE) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this? I also changed your `mutate_at` function to the more recent version using `across` and `where`:

```
  list_df |> 
     map_if(~any(.x$ID %in%newIDdf$ID) , ~ .x |> 
              mutate(ID = reduce2(newIDdf$ID, newIDdf$IDagr, 
                                  .init= ID, 
                                  str_replace)) %>%
              mutate(Name = case_when(ID == "Z" ~ "Z_name",
                                      ID == "Y" ~ "Y_name",
                                      TRUE ~ Name)) %>%
              group_by(ID) %>% 
              mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.))) %>%
              distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE))
```

**Output**:

```
$A
  ID   Name       Var1       Var2       Var3
1  a a_name  0.1015844  0.6306434  0.5058593
2  b b_name -0.1420690  0.5152645  0.2497879
3  c c_name  0.5841423  1.2883330  0.5297098
4  Z Z_name  1.6645565  0.2307524 -1.0418045
5  Y Y_name -0.1293767 -2.4152871 -0.1935843

$B
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
  ID    Name     Var1   Var2
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a     a_name -0.512 -0.119
2 b     b_name -2.14  -0.834
3 Z     Z_name  0.468  2.54 

$C
# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID    Name    Var1  Var2
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Y     Y_name 1.15  0.162
2 Z     Z_name 0.790 2.03
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, your solution is almost what I want , but do you think its possible to have Var1 and Var2 of B and C simply numeric columns and not a named lists ?

Comment: Yes, it came from the `list(. = sum(.)))` argument in the `mutate` call, if you remove it the output looks like the one in the edit I just made.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the approach below yields your desird output. Btw. we don't need `map_if` we can use `across(where())`. Also, we don't need `reduce2()` but can pass a lookup vector (below created with `set_names()`) to `str_replace_all()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)


list_df %>% 
  map_if(~ any(.x$ID %in% newIDdf$ID),
         ~ .x %>% 
           mutate(ID = str_replace_all(ID, set_names(newIDdf$IDagr, newIDdf$ID)),
                  Name = case_when(ID == "Z" ~ "Z_name",
                                   ID == "Y" ~ "Y_name",
                                   TRUE ~ Name)
                  ) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.))) %>% 
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
  )

#> $A
#>   ID   Name       Var1       Var2       Var3
#> 1  a a_name -0.9958825 -0.4822998 -0.5283220
#> 2  b b_name  0.5309721  0.7133405 -1.1024029
#> 3  c c_name -1.2049361  0.2681276  0.1179077
#> 4  Z Z_name -0.7167132 -1.0513967 -1.5125656
#> 5  Y Y_name -0.5056531  0.6273818  1.4781721
#> 
#> $B
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>   ID    Name     Var1  Var2
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a     a_name -0.967  2.78
#> 2 b     b_name -0.814  1.37
#> 3 Z     Z_name  0.354  2.33
#> 
#> $C
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   ID    Name    Var1   Var2
#>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Y     Y_name -2.71 -0.852
#> 2 Z     Z_name -2.06 -1.52
```

Data from OP

```r
list_df <- list(A = data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "Z", "Y"),
                               Name = c("a_name", "b_name", "c_name", "Z_name", "Y_name"), 
                               Var1 = rnorm(5),
                               Var2 = rnorm(5),
                               Var3 = rnorm(5)),
                B = data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "z1", "z2", "z3"),
                               Name = c("a_name", "b_name", "z1_name", "z2_name", "z3_name"),
                               Var1 = rnorm(5),
                               Var2 = rnorm(5)),
                C = data.frame(ID =  c("y1", "y2", "z1", "z2", "z3"),
                               Name = c("y1_name", "y2_name", "z1_name", "z2_name", "z3_name"),
                               Var1 = rnorm(5),
                               Var2 = rnorm(5)))

# a dataframe of correspondance for aggregation operations
newIDdf <- data.frame(ID =  c("y1", "y2", "z1", "z2", "z3"),
                      IDagr =  c("Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>